# Would the removal of the most upstream receptacle cause two separate GCFI outlets to go dead?

Tags: electrical, bathroom

The two GCFIs are in each bathroom of the apartment. One of them is downstream from the outlet I disconnected and its on the same circuit. But, the other GCFI is in adjacent bathroom which is on a separate circuit. Oddly, the light switch in BR#2 still works fine. BR#1 power is completely gone. Which I expected,since it’s on the same circuit as the outlet I removed. Why would the other GCFI die? Is related or a coincidence?

Comment: Where is the outlet you disconnected located at? Can you post a photo of the inside of its box?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It’s located directly in front of the breaker box. All the other receptacles in question are behind it.  The outlet seems to be ‘middle of the run’ type. It had 3 pigtailed wire groups with 4’

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel wires in each group. The 4th going directly from the pigtail to the Screw

Comment: Is it in cable? Were there any red wires in there?